# Failed to build iOS project

Tags: xcode, react-native, webstorm

I'm developing an app with React Native using WebStorm and I've installed the Xcode Simulator and the simulator itself comes up but the app itself doesn't appear. When I run

```bash
react-native run-ios
```

I get the following error message:

> xcodebuild: error: The workspace named "MyApp" does not contain a scheme named "MyApp". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the workspace.

Info about Xcode Simulator:

```text
Version 14.3.1 (994)
SimulatorKit 629
CoreSimulator 920.3
```

Just a side note: the program has worked before. I have changed my laptop. When I then tried to install it on the new laptop, I get the error.

I have tried several solutions online but none of them have helped.

- I've tried to delete the build folder multiple times, still same.
- I have tried to build with the `.xcworkspace` file, but the same problem occurs

What is causing the error? I feel like that the program is now been setup wrong... Is it because I'm running the program completely wrong?

Comment: 1. Did you install pods via npx pod-install?
2. Did you change from Intel to Apple Silicon?
3. Can you post the xcode build logs?

Comment: @MichaelBahl Thanks, I still got the same error, but after re-installing the CocoaPods I fixed that error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your application name in the schema section. It's look like this that your application name and schema name is different so you getting this error.

Comment: Where is the scheme section? I've only found the Application name, which is in App.js, but where can I find/edit the scheme name?

Comment: Please check this link https://satvasolutions.com/set-up-ios-environments-using-xcode-schemes-production-sandbox/